# Padding an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Want to know if this is possible.
I have an array say

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'green' )
```

I want to create an array from above array as

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'red (2)', 'red (3)', 'red (4)','red (5)'
                 'green', 'green (2)', 'green (3)', 'green (4)', 'green (5)' );
```

What I have tried:

```
$a = array('red ','green');
 print_r($a);

 foreach( $a as $value ) {
  for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
     $b = array_pad($a, $i, $value.' ('.$i.')');
  }
}
print_r($b);
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Show some codesamples

Comment: Please ask a question. Also, please explain in more detail *exactly how* you want to modify the original array.

Comment: There are no builtin function for this.

Comment: @DKSan Yes

$a = array('red ','green');
print_r($a);
$i=0;
 
foreach( $a as $value ) {
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
$b[] = array_pad($a, $i, $value.' ('.$i.')');
}
print_r($b);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'green' );

for ($count=1; $count < 5; $count++) { 

    $sum = $count+1;
    array_push($colors,"red($sum)");
    array_push($colors,"green($sum)");
}

rsort($colors);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($colors);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do using a simple `foreach`

```
<?php
$colors = array( 'red', 'green' );
$new_colors = array();
echo "<pre>";
foreach($colors as $v)
{
    $new_colors[] = $v;
    foreach(range(2,5) as $v1)
    {
    $new_colors[]= $v." ( $v1 )";
    }
}
print_r($new_colors);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => red ( 2 )
    [2] => red ( 3 )
    [3] => red ( 4 )
    [4] => red ( 5 )
    [5] => green
    [6] => green ( 2 )
    [7] => green ( 3 )
    [8] => green ( 4 )
    [9] => green ( 5 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do custom code for this

like

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'green' );
$newarray = array();
$count=0;
foreach($colors as $index=>$key)
{
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
        if($i>=2)
        $newarray[$count++] = $key.' ('.$i.')';
        else if($i==0)
        $newarray[$count++] = $key;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => red (2)
    [2] => red (3)
    [3] => red (4)
    [4] => red (5)
    [5] => green
    [6] => green (2)
    [7] => green (3)
    [8] => green (4)
    [9] => green (5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple array_push will do

```
$colors = array( 'red', 'green' );
$i=1;
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++)
{
    array_push($colors,$colors[0].'('.$i.')');
    array_push($colors,$colors[1].'('.$i.')');
}

print_r($colors);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * array_repeat_values()
 * 
 * repeate values of an array
 * 
 * @param   array $input
 * @param   int $multiplier
 * @return  array
 */
function array_repeat_values(array $input, $multiplier)
{
    $r = array();

    foreach($input as &$v)
        for($i = 1; $i <= (int) $multiplier; ++$i) {
            if($i < 2)
                $r[] = $v;
            else
                $r[] = $v . " ($i)";
        }

    return $r;
}

$colors = array( 'red', 'green' );

var_dump(array_repeat_values($colors, 5));
```